# Exception in android webView

Tags: android, css, webview

I have an exception when I try to launch my application:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.webkit.WebView.loadUrl(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

This is my code in my Main Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/page.html");
}
```

My webView in composed of two files: page.html and style.css, both in the folder called "Assets".

Comment: You're missing the `super.onCreate()` and `setContentView()` calls that should be at the start of your `onCreate()` method.

Comment: Sorry, wrong copy/paste, it is already in my onCreate method.

Comment: The `WebView` with ID `webView` is apparently not in the `activity_main` layout, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is likely that your `findViewById(R.id.webView)` is not actually finding a `WebView`. Ensure that the `WebView` you are looking for does exist. If it doesn't legitimately exist, then you should stop your processing or add code to create a new `WebView` or whatever your code should do in case of a failure.